# installation of device softwares doesn't show in control panel

Tags: windows-8.1, installation

Softwares installed through the "device manger", don't show up in the control panel. Why is it so? Does this mean that the installation is not complete? I just installed driver for my AMD 8600M series and there are no shortcuts to AMDs catalyst control and it doesn't show up in the control panel.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you sure you installed the AMD Catalyst Software, or just the AMD Driver?

Comment: @Darius, Yes, since application without the "Video controller" in the device manager under unknown device was listed. I right clicked it and hit update software. After installation was complete, it showed AMD Radeon 8600M series under display adapters in the device manager, however, it was not listed in the control panel. I'm not just considering only this case though. E.g. for installing printers, if you use the device manager, the printer works fine, however, there is no list in the control panel of the driver software.

Comment: To my knowledge if you choose devices on the Device Manager and do update software - it will only provide you with the Driver for the Device but not including all the "additional software". AMD Catalyst is an additional software to run additional features of the GPU but it is not required for your graphic card to run properly. If you want to use AMD Catalyst, you will need to download it directly from the AMD website.

Comment: @Darius, is the CCC for amd gone? There seems to be something like(Crimson Relive ) whose interface is very different to CCC.

Comment: @bzal, that is right. See here the news of the switch http://www.windowscentral.com/good-bye-amd-catalyst-drivers-and-hello-radeon-software-crimson

Answer (score 0):

Installing from the device driver just installs the basic software required to control the device. Additional softwares should be downloaded manually. (From the above comment).